# Calculating optimal path to improving your gear

Tags: statistics

There is this game with the following inputs

- Equipment (or simply gear) with $n$ upgradeble slots at a cost of $p_g$
- Scrolls that consume these upgrade slots:

  - 10% scroll. Chance of 10% to improve gear stats by $imp_1%$ at cost $p_1$
  - 30% scroll. Chance of 30% to improve gear stats by $imp_3$ at cost $p_3$, but it it fails it has a 50% chance to destroy the item
  - 60% scroll. Chance of 60% to improve gear stats by $imp_6%$ at cost $p_6$
  - 70% scroll. Chance of 70% to improve gear stats by $imp_7%$ at cost $p_7$, but it it fails it has a 50% chance to destroy the item
- A players choice to use $tt$ amount of 10% and 30% scrolls (which provide the largest benefit at the biggest risk)

Given these inputs, what is the optimal path of upgrading, where all slots are consumed?

Forgive me for my appalling math skills, but I have simply brute forced 200000 randomly chosen combinations to come to a optimal solution from where a pattern emerges - is the equipment cost low, use the low cost scrolls first. If the equipment cost is high, use the high cost scrolls first. I have made an example [written in javascript](https://tm.tyron.at/pub/scrolling.html), however I then realized, it does not account for destroyed equipment. I can't really fathom how the math works on this, but right now, from what I can understand my current algorithm includes the cost of all $n$ scrolls, even if the item was already destroyed at slot $0\dots n-2$

How do i correctly include that in my cost calculation?

```
    // Scrolls is a n sized list of numbers. 0 = 60% scroll, 1 = 70% scroll, 2 = 30% scroll, 3 = 10% scroll
    // Price is the cost of the equipment
    function getCost(scrolls, price) {
        var boomChance = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var newPrice = 0;
            if (scrolls[i] == 0) {
                newPrice = (price + p6) / 0.6;
            }
            if (scrolls[i] == 1) { 
                newPrice = (price + p7) / 0.7;
                boomChance += (1 - boomChance) * 0.3 * 0.5;
            }
            if (scrolls[i] == 2) { 
                newPrice = (price + p3) / 0.3;
                boomChance += (1 - boomChance) * 0.7 * 0.5;
            }
            if (scrolls[i] == 3) { 
                newPrice = (price + p1) / 0.1;
            }
            
            //price += (newPrice - price) * aliveChance; - not correct
            var aliveChance = 1 - boomChance;
            price += (newPrice - price);
        }
        return price;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, it is unclear to me what a "scroll" is: are the four scrolls the four action types which can be taken at any time t? Also, you say that scroll 30% offers the biggest potential reward and the biggest risk, but that does not appear in your statement; for example, it seems to me that the 70% scroll is similar. If there is some ordering of the constants such as $imp1<imp6<imp7<imp3$, and an ordering in the costs as well, this would be good to know... If there is an unknown and this becomes revealed somehow, that is important info as well.

Comment: Not entirely sure this could help, but an approach to modeling the chance at destruction is to have the payoff go to minus infinity. Depending on what the optimization looks like, this could yield a solution at $t$. For the rest, with a better understanding of the problem, I might be able to see if a dynamic optimization (i.e. for the full trajectory) or a local one (i.e. at each $t$) is doable...

Comment: @sg1234 yes the 4 scrolls are the four action types that can be taken in any order on the available number of upgrades per equipment piece. The is no unknown reward, they are known from the start.
The potential reward depends on the type of equipment. But for example one of them (weapons) it is 10%/30%: +5 attack; 60%/70%: +2 attack

Comment: Sorry I had missed your link to the example you had given. Apparently, the player does not play against anyone, i.e. there is no other player strategy to account for? In this case, this is not a game in the theoretical sense and you should probably remove the expression "game theory" from both your title and your tags. This might be more of an optimal control problem, and I won't be of much help in that case.

Comment: ok, removed, thanks for the info